# Modify .bat file to not only launch simultaneous processes, but also close them

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am developing a simple multiplayer card game on windows. For testing purposes I want to spawn the client 4 times, each from its own CMD prompt so that I can see stdout separate for each instance.

My current startclient.bat file is:

```
echo "starting 4 player clients" 
start cmd /k ..\.venv\Scripts\python.exe player_main.py &
start cmd /k ..\.venv\Scripts\python.exe player_main.py &
start cmd /k ..\.venv\Scripts\python.exe player_main.py &
start cmd /k ..\.venv\Scripts\python.exe player_main.py &
pause
```

In total, this opens up 5 CMD prompts and 4 game clients.

If I close a CMD prompt linked to a game client, the game clients (python) closes too, which is great!

If I close the main CMD prompt (startup.bat) the other 4 CMD prompts do not close.
How can I modify my .bat file so that when I close the main CMD prompt everything closes at  once?

Comment: Why are you using `cmd /K` to run the executable `python.exe`? why not simply running `start "" "..\.venv\Scripts\python.exe" "player_main.py"`? and why are you appending an `&`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will let you play with ["Truth or Consequences"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_or_Consequences) however this works for me.
[image]

```
taskkill /t /fi "windowtitle eq Player2*"
SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to process with PID 26904, child of PID 26364.
SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to process with PID 26364, child of PID 24012.

taskill /t /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe"
ERROR: The process with PID 23176 (child process of PID 24012) could not be terminated.
Reason: The process cannot terminate itself.
ERROR: The process with PID 24012 (child process of PID 7440) could not be terminated.
```

The game is A Foot dear Watson.

I could play dirty and /F (force) the console to close externally but since you have added a pause then just close the 4 shells after you "Press any Key" and let the Fifth close itself naturally and cleanly. The timeout can be removed once you are happy the process works, whether shells were already closed or not.

You can adapt the following to suit your needs

```
Title Master & Mode 26,10 & color 50
Start "Player1" %comspec%  /K "Color 40 & Mode 30,10 & Pause"
Start "Player2" %comspec%  /K "Color 20 & Mode 30,10 & Pause"
Start "Player3" %comspec%  /K "Color 10 & Mode 30,10 & Pause"
Start "Player4" %comspec%  /K "Color 60 & Mode 30,10 & Pause"

Pause

taskkill /t /fi "windowtitle eq Player1*"
taskkill /t /fi "windowtitle eq Player2*"
taskkill /t /fi "windowtitle eq Player3*"
taskkill /t /fi "windowtitle eq Player4*"
timeout 4
exit /b
```

Comment: Thanks, worked great. Had to make 2 modifications. First a * at the end of windowtitle was required as the window title was appended with the game launch command. Second, without /F my application would not close (maybe due to the event loop).